# How can I get mac addresses from Users?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, mac-os-x

I want to make SharePoint List with all users computer info, instead of manually go to each PC in our company, how can I retrieve their PC info, Including mac address which what I want most for networking troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. You would need an agent (application) on the computer that pushed this information to the SharePoint list. The browser does not have these details as it would be a potential security risks.

I would suggest another tool, i.e. InTune, ServiceNow, or some other tool that specializes in computer asset management.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a different approach than SharePoint. This might be a direction to investigate, using PowerShell: https://shellgeek.com/powershell-get-computerinfo
BTW: The output of course could very well be written to a SharePoint List